# mysql.connector in PyCharm creates a segmentation fault when running connect() with kwargs

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm, segmentation-fault

I am trying to setup a mysql client with Python. My mysql server is currently in my ubuntu system.

The problem is, if I run the module with PyCharm run, it generates a segmentation fault (see error below). However, I ran it with the PyCharm debugger, the PyCharm console, the Python console, and the linux bash and it worked correctly. I ran out of ideas of what the problem could be.

The program is:

```
import faulthandler; faulthandler.enable()
import mysql.connector

dbparams = dict(host='localhost', user='user', password='password')
connection_empty = mysql.connector.connect()
print(connection_empty)
connection = mysql.connector.connect(**dbparams)

print(connection)
show_db_query = 'SHOW DATABASES'
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(show_db_query)
for element in cursor:
    print(element)
```

I run the program with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /path/to/program/example.py PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1
```

The traceback is the following:

```
<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x7f06c1527e48>
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f06c16a0740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 391 in __new__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 502 in create_default_context
  File "$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 448 in switch_to_ssl
  File "$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 209 in _do_auth
  File "$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 355 in _open_connection
  File "$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1003 in connect
  File "$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 108 in __init__
  File "$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 278 in connect
  File "$HOME/path/to/program/example.py", line 8 in <module>

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

System is ubuntu 18.04

PyCharm version is 2019.1.1

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33

mysql-connection-python 8.0.23

Any ideas would be appretiated, thanks!

Comment: upddate your python version, under pythonv3.9.1 this runs without problem(windows)

Answer (score 0):

So, I updated my python version as nbk was suggesting (I did to python3.7 because I had it already installed).

And it turns out to work now. Unfortunately, I do not know what the problem was.